# Selecting rows except some others

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID |   fruit |   who |  days_ago |
----------------------------------
1  |  orange |  Adam |         2 |
2  |  banana |  Adam |         3 |
3  |   apple |  Adam |         4 |
4  |    kiwi |  Adam |         2 |
6  |  banana | Jimmy |         3 |
7  |   apple | Jimmy |         5 |
8  |  grapes | Jimmy |         1 |
9  |  orange | Carol |         2 |
10 |  grapes | Carol |         6 |
11 |   lemon | Carol |         3 |
```

And my problem is:
The table contained information about who bought what fruit and when (when is an extra information I just need to keep).
I need to select all the fruits that Adam didn't buy.

```
ID |   fruit |   who |  days_ago |
----------------------------------
8  |  grapes | Jimmy |         1 |
10 |  grapes | Carol |         6 |
11 |   lemon | Carol |         3 |
```

And if Jimmy bought them, I don't want to know if Carol bought them too.
And my result should be this:

```
ID |   fruit |   who |  days_ago |
----------------------------------
8  |  grapes | Jimmy |         1 |
11 |   lemon | Carol |         3 |
```

When I GROUP BY fruit, I lose information about who and days_ago (I don't understand how they're chosen).
And when I select unique fruits and drop all that Adam bought, I lose grapes which both Jimmy and Carol bought.

This isn't the actual table I'm working on. Just a simplification of what I'm struggling with.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY`, it's combining the data into one row.  Try `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(who)`.

Comment: mysql extends the group by.  Each non-aggregated field in the select that is not in the group by, the system is free to choose a RANDOM value in the list of values for that field. " The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. "  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the fruits that Adam didn't buy, you can use a subquery for this.  Have the subquery select the fruits he *did* buy, and then have the main query say "not those".

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit NOT IN(
    SELECT fruit
    FROM fruits
    WHERE who = "Adam"
)
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3974d/1

When you use `GROUP BY`, you are combining multiple rows into one.  The other rows' data isn't gone, just hidden.  Try using `GROUP_CONCAT` to see the list of `who` fields.

```
SELECT ID, fruit,
    GROUP_CONCAT(who) as who,
    GROUP_CONCAT(days_ago) AS days_ago
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit NOT IN(
    SELECT fruit
    FROM fruits
    WHERE who = "Adam"
)
GROUP BY fruit
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3974d/3

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was as easy as I expected it would be.

Comment: NOT IN is dangerous with nulls. Avoid at all costs

Comment: @Drew: I'm assuming that won't be an issue here, but what's the alternative then?  `NOT EXISTS`?